# Xaml errors in Xamarin: all types not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I designed an Android application on Adobe XD and through a plugin I exported all my assets to XAML.

I created a new project on Xamarin and immediately pasted the generated XAML in the MainPage.xaml file  within the stacklayout. so like below:

```
<stacklayout>
      <Grid Uid="Google Pixel 6 Pro – 1"  Width="412" Height="778" Background="#0000" ClipToBounds="True" >
            <Border  Width="225" Height="43" BorderBrush="#0000" Margin="171,18,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Canvas  Width="36" Height="30" Margin="24,24,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Border  Width="24" Height="24" BorderBrush="#FFFF" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="6"  />


....
```

The problem is that anything I pasted in the layout is giving me the below error message:

> The type 'border' was not found. verify that you are not missing an
> assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
> Xaml0414: namespace is missing

I'm getting this for every component. Border, canvas, textblock, and even sub parameters like uid.

This is what i have at the top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DemoXAML.MainPage">
```

I'm not quite sure what I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that this code converter that you used did convert your code to XAML, But the XAML is WPF and not Xamarin.Forms(Yes not everything between them is the same).

```
<Border  Width="225" Height="43" BorderBrush="#0000" Margin="171,18,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Is WPF XAML not Xamarin, The closest to it is you use Xamarin.Forms Frame but they are not the same.

A little googling between the two will help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear response!

Comment: Happy to help mate :)